# Setting the number of intervals in ASP.Net Charts with variable data range

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, intervals

I'm trying to set the number of intervals of a Y-Axis on a chart to be 4.  The range of the max Yvalue is just about anything, so I can't preset the Min/Max and .Interval property.

Currently, the Chart is only outputting 0 and a round number somewhat near the max value.

I'd like it to continue using the rounded values, just always show 4 instead of the 1 it's defaulting to.

I've tried area.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount, but it seems I have to set the value of the Interval or that to work. (There's no .NumberOfIntervals or anything).

I'm trying to avoid having to calculate the Max value, and then manually determine some decent rounded number to use as the interval.

Thanks!